# gulp-typescript compiler throws errors on readonly modifier

Tags: angular, typescript, gulp-typescript, angular2-material

I've just upgraded my app to use `Angular 2 rc.6` and `Angular Material 2 alpha 8-1`. These packages rely on `typescript 2` and the latter makes use of the new `readonly` modifier.

I use `gulp-typescript` to compile my .ts files and I'm now getting a lot of errors from files that use the `readonly` modifier. For instance, this line:

```
readonly change: Observable<MdButtonToggleChange>;
```

Throws these errors during compilation:

> error TS1005: '=' expected.
>
> error TS1005: ';' expected.
>
> error TS1005: '(' expected.

I think this is probably because `gulp-typescript` internally uses `typescript 1.8.10`, which does not have the `readonly` modifier.

None of my own code uses `readonly`; The only files throwing errors are third-party typescript definition files (`.d.ts`) from `Angular 2 Material` packages. The files in question are all within my `nodes_module/` folder, and I've tried to ignore them by having the following in `tsconfig.json`:

```
"exclude": [
  "node_modules",
  "typings"
]
```

The errors still show up though.

- Can I solve this?
- If not, is there an easy way to get the compiler to ignore `.d.ts` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to add a TypeScript 2.0.2 RC dependency to your project (`npm install typescript@rc --save-dev`) and to pass it to `gulp-typescript` using the unofficial [`typescript`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript#typescript-version) option:

```
[...].pipe(ts({
    typescript: require('typescript')
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for the note. As I wrote in the OP, the errors are thrown only by `.d.ts` files belonging to `ng-Material`. The `Angular` library itself throws no error.  All errors come from `node_modules/@angular2-material/`

Comment: I should have paid closer attention to the question; it was something I was anticipating having to deal with when switching to RC6. It seems that the Angular team have done more that just move to the `esm` source, as said source no longer seems to include `readonly` properties. Something of a relief, I guess.

Comment: I came to post my solution after getting the problem fixed and I just noticed that you changed your answer to the correct one. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, I snipped out the irrelevant Angular 2 stuff and cleaned it up a bit. I should have posted a comment to let you know. Hope you didn't spend too much time looking into the solution.

Answer (score 3):

@cartant got the right answer yesterday but I only saw it a minute ago. Basically, the solution is to get `gulp-typescript` to use the `typescript 2` instead of the built-in `typescript 1.8`.  Here is how:

**1.** I added `typescript 2.0.2` as a devDependency in **package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {    
  "gulp-typescript": "^2.13.6",
  "typescript": "^2.0.2",
}
```

**2.** I ran `npm install typescript@2.0.2`

**3.** I edited how I created my `gulp-typescript` project in **gulpfile.js**

From:

```
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');
```

To:

```
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json', {
    //Use TS version installed by NPM instead of gulp-typescript's built-in
    typescript: require('typescript')
});
```

[More info.](https://github.com/ivogabe/gulp-typescript#typescript-version)  Now the compile-time errors are gone :-)